# не могу прочитать относительный пусть node.js после сборки

Tags: node.js, build, electron, файловые-пути

Собираю electron.js

```
 electron-builder --win portable
```

Мне нужно создать/получить файл который находится рядом с exe

```
    try{
        const sign = await fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "sign.json"));
        return proxy; 
    }
    catch(e){
        return false;
    }
```

Он его просто не видит

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/ru/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname

Comment: @nörbörnën const appPath = app.getAppPath(); сделал так ```async () => {

    try{
        const proxy = await fs.writeFile(path.join(appPath, "ta.txt"), `${app.getAppPath()}`);
        return proxy; 
    }
    catch(e){
        return false;
    }
}``` не помогает

Comment: А вы пытались выводить результат `path.join(appPath, "ta.txt")`?

Comment: @OliverPatterson Да, оно выводит результат во временную папку

Comment: Попробуйте вывести в `catch` какой нибудь лог и узнайте в чем проблема.

Comment: @OliverPatterson я сделал вывод пути, оно вовзоащает путь из папки temp а мне нужно как-то получить путь к файлу exe который вообще по другому пути находится

Comment: Покажите объявление переменной `appPath`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147491/discussion-between-oliver-patterson-and-xoheveras).

Comment: прочитайте доку и выберите подходящий вашему случаю ключ name. Скорее всего это `exe`. Поэкспериментируйте с ключами.